# how to port data from a java file to open office spreadsheet?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I have stored data in a file and I want to represent the data in an organized format in open office spreadsheet? I found something similar for MS Excel in JExcel but I only have open office on my computer. The net searches did not have relevant links.

Comment: Open Office can open up .xls files, why not try to write the data out using this JExcel lib and open it up in Open Office to see how it looks

Comment: How about apache poi ?

Comment: Oh yeah! I guess that will work thanks. But, is there any way to get it in ODF Spreadsheet format

Comment: Another option is to use the [CSVPrinter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.4/apidocs/index.html) from [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to create a csv file that can be read by Calc.

Comment: Apache POI will work ... I have tried it before

Comment: Apache POI did the trick, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

What about [Apache ODF Toolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/)?